# sending directory's path as an argument to a function in clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to send a string that is a path of a directory to a function.how do I do that in Clojure?
I tried doing the following but it didn't work

```
(defn make-asm-file [d]
  (doseq [f (.listFiles d)]
     (if 
         ( and (=(str(last (split (.getName f) #"\."))) "vm") (not (.isDirectory f))) 
         (translate f d))))

(make-asm-file "~\SimpleAdd")
```

Comment: Why do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: `"~\SimpleAdd"` is a string - you need a `File` object that responds to `.listFiles`

Comment: thanks Kyle.do u have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Be aware of Java \ escaping, and file separators on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following,

```
(defn find-files
  [regexp directory]
  (filter #(and (.isFile %)
                (re-find regexp (str %)))
          (.listFiles (clojure.java.io/file directory))))

(doseq [f (find-files #".vm$" "~/SimpleAdd")]
  (translate f))
```

In this case `(java.io.File. d)` would work instead of `(clojure.java.io/file d)` as well. You could also use [file-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/file-seq) instead of listfiles, but that would include all *.vm files in subdirs.